# Matlab emit sound every second

Tags: matlab

I've done a function `playSound(f)` which looks like this:

```
function playSound(f)

    fs = 44100;
    t = 0:1/fs:1;

    y = sin(2.*pi.*f.*t);

    sound(y,fs,16);

end
```

I'm using this function in another function with the following code:

```
while i <= y
    b = bin2dec(bits(i:i+k-1));
    freq = 2000-frequencyInterval+b*deltaFreq;
    playSound(freq);
    pause(1);
    i = i + k;
end
```

What I'm expecting from the last piece of code is getting a succession of sinusoids with different frequencies each lasting one second and one after another. But I've noticed that this is completely unreliable and I'm not getting exactly one second of one sin directly followed by another one.

Is there a more precise way to tell Matlab to play my sounds one by one, each during a certain time (no more no less) and without interruptions (or anything else in the middle)?

Comment: I'd build a big signal by stitching all the individual sinusoids together, and then play that

Comment: Oh, or that, much easier if you know in advance what you want to play :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab pause does not provide millisecond precision, even when measured by its internal tic-toc timer. For example:

> tic;pause(1);toc
>
> Elapsed time is 1.006905 seconds.
>
> tic;pause(0.001);toc
>
> Elapsed time is 0.018834 seconds.

If you can't 'pre-render' the entire sound sequence as suggested in the comments, I'd use a tool such as [Psychophysics toolbox](http://psychtoolbox.org/) that can take care both of timing and audio playback.

Comment: Yes, and it's also worse than that. Try `s = sin(linspace(0, 1, 10000)*400*pi); tic; for i=1:N; sound(s, 10000); end; toc` for small values of N :(.

Answer (score 1):

Playing sound elegantly requires some low-level access and buffering and what not. Matlab's `sound()` function does not provide such access, and will not do what you want, unfortunately. However, if you've a recent Matlab, you will find `audioplayer` does do what you want, that's exactly the role it's designed for. Because of the need to 'play nice' with your sound hardware, you will have to invest a little more time in making it behave.

Start at "doc audioplayer".